# Is there a Mysql function to see if there's one result or more than one result MySQL query?

Tags: mysql

We're writing code to match submissions to people. Given first name, last name, etc. we try to narrow down to a single result. However, the submissions for addresses or other contact info might be spelled wrong, so we prefer to match on a few criteria as possible--hence multiple steps to finding a match.

Here's the algorithm:

```
Count by first name and last name
if count == 1 // done

if count > 1, count by first name, last name, email
if count == 1 // done

// etc.
```

What is the best way to tell if we'll get one person result or not given a query?

The obvious answer is just to count, but that is unnecessary since we don't need the number, we just need to see if it's plural results or singular result (the matching may be bad enough to return a count of thousands). Another option is to limit to 2 results, which minimizes the counting, but adds somewhat confusing code (why do a count if it's limited as well?)

Is there a preferred method for doing this?

Comment: email is generally unique to a person.  I'd prefer to use it 1st over first/last name if it's a required field.  It seems like what you're trying to do is identify the LOGICAL key on which you can identify a specific person.  name even first/last is seldom enough.  You get Rob Smith which could be Robert Smith  or Robert Smith Jr.. etc.  email seems much more granular as a domain typically doesn't allow duplicates!  You may be able to use `group by with rollup`  for example... `Select FName, Lname, Email, count(*)
from table
Group by (FName, Lname, Email) with rollup
Having count(*) = 1`

Comment: Email might be a bad example. If all we're given is a first name, last name, street name, street number, city, etc. then a typo in any of those means we won't match. Additionally, the user might decide to use a dummy email address.

Comment: Yeah OK, NM. I don't think I understood the question on first read.

Comment: What if another John Smith uses your system? Given your logic, you couldn't tell if it's the same person or not. You need a unique person identifier, and first name + last name is **not** unique. Email is a good choice, verified of course to prevent someone accidentally or intentionally entering someone else's email. Most websites operate this way when handling user input; I suggest you adopt this approach too.

Comment: This is an online submission form for people to pledge--not for system users with a login--and we may or may not have records of them in our database. We need some sort of matching strategy where we check to see if we've found one person or not, with stages to get more and more complicated in our querying. First name, last name is a simplified example. People won't know their unique id so they can't just use that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MySQL does not have a function that will tell you if you have 1 match or more.
Your options, as you said, is to `count(*)` or to use `LIMIT 2`.

The LIMIT option should be faster to execute, but I am going to assume that the performance difference between the two is not huge.
This is something you should verify on real data, and of course you should have an index on `(first_name, last_name)`.

In that case, you can save the second query run by running a single query:

```
SELECT first_name, last_name, email
FROM users
WHERE first_name = 'foo'
AND last_name = 'bar'
```

Then, in your code, you can easily get the count of results.

If 1 -> you got it.

If more -> you already have the email in your result set and use can use it to filter the record you need.